# как получить адрес поля структуры?

Tags: c++, c, указатели, структуры

Написал программу на вывод чисел в байтах и адреса хранения  этих байтов,но преподаватель говорит,что адреса полей хранятся в сложных типах данных хранятся не последовательно,а мой вариант программы не верен.
Собственно вопрос,как получить адрес поля структуры ?
Код приложил:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char *byte_ptr;

void print_int(byte_ptr start, int size)
{
    cout << "Вывод числа типа int ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("\n|%p|%2x|", &start[i], start[i]);
}

void print_float(byte_ptr start, int size)
{
    cout << "Вывод числа типа float ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("\n|%p|%2x|", &start[i], start[i]);
}

void print_double(byte_ptr start, int size)
{
    cout << "Вывод числа типа double ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("\n|%p|%2x|", &start[i], start[i]);
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    struct Numbers
    {
        int x;
        float y;
        double z;
    } Byte;
    Byte.x = 15;
    Byte.y = 15;
    Byte.z = 15;

    print_int((byte_ptr) &Byte.x, sizeof(Byte.x));
    cout << endl;

    print_float((byte_ptr) &Byte.y, sizeof(Byte.y));
    cout << endl;

    print_double((byte_ptr) &Byte.z, sizeof(Byte.z));
    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Как это выглядит на консоли 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Зачем написано три одинаковых функции? Почему в первой есть отличие (найдите сами)? Какое отношение вообще правильность программы имеет к тому, как хранятся данные в структурах?

Comment: Преподаватель говорит,что в сложных типах данных используется выравнивание полей, поэтому поля структуры (именно поля) могут находится и не в последовательных адресах.Вопрос в том,как это все наглядно показать на консоли ?

Comment: Поменяйте местами `float` и `double` в структуре.

Comment: Зачем,ничего же не изменится?Я проверил

Comment: Почему не изменится? В умолчательных настройках выравнивания по вашей распечатке адресов будет хорошо видно, что после первого поля образовалась неиспользуемая "дырка" размером 4 байта.

Comment: @AnT: адреса в вопросе в приведённом выводе 32-битные -- для `struct {int,double,float}` с `-m32` у меня тоже нет дырки: `{0с-0f, 10-17,18-1b}`. [`clang -Wpadded`](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) ничего не показывает с `-m32` в этом случае. Для 64-бит, [вижу "дырку"](http://ideone.com/icBzix). Не ясно о чём преподаватель говорит: `&struct_.member` возвращает адрес, который всегда к `(unsigned char*)` можно привести и [прочитать](https://goo.gl/A6js7H) (вне зависимости от alignment и padding в struct).

Answer (score 2):

> как получить адрес поля структуры?

Так вы же правильно это делаете:

```
(byte_ptr)&Byte.x
```

Правда, приведение указателей к другому типу - не очень хорошая идея, но это уже другой вопрос.

Далее, в функциях `print_...` вы пытаетесь разбить это число на байты и вывести их по порядку с адресом, но почему-то в первом случае забыли оператор взятия адреса:

```
printf("\n|%p|%2x|", &start[i], start[i]);
```

Данные хранятся в структурах последовательно, но между ними могут появляться пустые пространства. Например, если у вас 32-разрядная архитектура, и первое поле структуры имеет тип char, а второе - float, то между ними появятся 3 пустых байта. Это называется выравниванием.

И, да, AnT верно заметил, что ваши три функции абсолютно одинаковы. Если вы в функцию, печатающую float, передадите адрес на double, то она правильно его напечатает.

---

UPD. Чтобы увидеть пустые пространства между полями структуры, нужно расположить эти поля так, чтобы это пространство потребовалось. Вот [здесь](https://tproger.ru/translations/art-of-structure-packing/) хорошо описано, когда и почему эти пространства появляются, и как их избежать.

В вашем случае, скорее всего, можно просто double поставить посередине. Или добавить char в начало.

Comment: А как вывести это выравнивание  на экран ?Я приложил скрин того как это выглядит сейчас

Comment: @vosure, например, так: `size_t filled_by = (char *)&Byte.z - (char *)&Byte.x - sizeof(Byte.x)`.

Comment: @vosure: на Linux, можно посмотреть как struct в памяти выглядит с помощью [pahole утилиты](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pahole) (`sudo apt install dwarves`). В вашем случае, можно вынести `struct Numbers` из `main()`, чтобы она стала видна и скомпилировать с debug инфо (`-g`). Тогда команда `gcc -g *.c && pahole a.out` покажет  расположение элементов в структуре.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать возможности препроцессора, то можно описать все поля в одном массиве структур и подробно все напечатать (вместе с промежутками между полями).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  struct {
    int x;
    double z;
    float y;
  } bytes = {1, 1, 0};

  struct {
    void *addr;
    size_t len;
    const char *type, *name;
  } info[] = {
#define FIELD(f,T) {&(f), sizeof(f), #T, #f}
    FIELD(bytes.x, int), FIELD(bytes.z, double), FIELD(bytes.y, float),
#undef FIELD    
    {&bytes + 1, 0}};

  unsigned char *b = (unsigned char *)&bytes,
    *eb = (unsigned char *)(&bytes + 1);
  printf("struct bytes (%p:%p %zu bytes) content:\n",
         b, eb, sizeof(bytes));

  for (size_t i = 0; info[i].len; i++) {
    printf("%p:%p %2zu %s %s\t: " ,
           info[i].addr, (char *)info[i].addr + info[i].len,
           info[i].len, info[i].type, info[i].name);
    for (eb = b + info[i].len; b < eb; b++)
      printf("%02x ", *b);
    for (; (void *)b != info[i + 1].addr; b++)
      printf(".. ");
    puts("");
  }
}
```

Получится что-то вроде такого (в 64-бит Linux)

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ tt.cpp -Wall -O3 -std=c++17
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out
struct bytes (0x7ffc4bf91040:0x7ffc4bf91058 24 bytes) content:
0x7ffc4bf91040:0x7ffc4bf91044  4 int bytes.x    : 01 00 00 00 .. .. .. .. 
0x7ffc4bf91048:0x7ffc4bf91050  8 double bytes.z : 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f 
0x7ffc4bf91050:0x7ffc4bf91054  4 float bytes.y  : 00 00 00 00 .. .. .. .. 
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Последний элемент массива описателей полей структуры надо инициализировать адресом, следующим за структурой и нулевой длиной.

Comment: Sorry, что оффтопик :)  Было бы интересно [мнение по этому вопросу](https://habrahabr.ru/post/325678/#comment_10156952), ветка про jmalloc и прочее. (ой, спалился)

Comment: @PinkTux, давайте уже завтра, я спать собрался...

Comment: OK, это не спешит.

Comment: @PinkTux, я прочел. Вас интересует мнение о http://jemalloc.net/jemalloc.3.html ? (или это в контексте restricted и volatile?) Похоже мощная либа, но нужна конкретная задача для стимула основательно ее изучить. А бенчмарки для сравнения со стандартной лнуксовой делали?

Comment: пока не ковырял подробно. Интересует в первую очередь не как аллокактор, а именно как средство отлова ошибок,с которыми якобы не справляется valgrind. Насчёт стимула согласен.